# CakePHP Find with Associated Model Condition

Tags: cakephp

I have 3 tables

```
Users (id, name, email)

Teams (id, name)

TeamUsers (id, team_id, user_id)
```

How do I find all the `users` who are not in team_id = 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways. Here's one:

```
$model = ClassRegistry::init('User');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM team_users where user_id = User.id AND team_id = 1';

$users = $model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        "NOT EXISTS ($query)"
    )
));
```

Which will result in:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users as User
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM team_users WHERE user_id = User.id AND team_id = 1
    )
```